# What does if($stmt) mean here?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have started learning PHP since 4 days. I found this code online while i was searching for **"Best practice to execute MySQL query in PHP"**. I can't determine , What does he use `if($stmt)` for ?

```
$stmt = $condb->prepare("DELETE FROM accounts WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->execute(
array(
"id" => 5
)
);

if($stmt){
   // Do Something
} else {
   // Do Something Else
}
```

Comment: It basically means that a prepared statement object exists and I can use the results in it to do something on them

Comment: Prepare returns a statement if it works, and false if it doesn't. It would make more sense to put the execute inside the if than before it.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya So , It will return true every time because he defined the obj in the first line **$stmt = $condb->prepare("DELETE FROM accounts WHERE id=:id");** .. I think that (If statement) here isn't needed unless it's used for another reason

Comment: @aynber Is **if($stmt)** equivalent to **if($stmt->execute())** ?

Comment: "Prepare returns a statement if it works, and false if it doesn't." @aynber i assume a better check would be `if(is_resource($stmt)) {...}` instead off `if($stmt){...}` or `if($stmt instanceof PDOStatement) {...}) {..}` or even `if(is_resource($stmt) && $stmt instanceof PDOStatement) {...}`

Comment: No, it's something completely different. `if($stmt)` is only checking to make sure that `$stmt` is something other than false. `$condb->prepare()` will return either false on failure, or a PDOStatement object on success. `if($stmt->execute())` will check to see if the execute function returned a non-false value.

Comment: @RaymondNijland That seems like overkill. `$stmt` will either be false or a PDOStatement. It won't ever be anything else with the code given.

Comment: "That seems like overkill. $stmt will either be false or a PDOStatement. It won't ever be anything else with the code given." well it's questionable @aynber i also said `if($stmt instanceof PDOStatement) {...})` .. You can get clearer code then using `if($stmt) {...}`

Comment: @aynber I got it .. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't pointed the source, probably it's a [`PDO::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) method which:

> If the database server successfully prepares the statement, [PDO::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) returns a [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object. If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, [PDO::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) returns **FALSE** or emits [PDOException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) (depending on [error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)).

And since it could be false it's better to put it in an if condition